# GMail HTML email making image 7000px high

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I have continuity (ish) in all other email clients (including hotmail), using gmail however is a different story.

An image which is 72px high is been scaled to 7000px high for an unknown reason, code:

```
<img src="headerbg.jpg" style="width:100%;height:70px;" />
```

Are there any common errors for gmail?

Also, when inspecting the element I see this (which as you can see most of it i am not putting in):

```
<img src="http://gallery.mailchimp.com/663dc47a790bab652488be03b/images/
headerbg.3.jpg"
style="width:100%;min-height:70px;border:0;
line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image has a very short width.  When you set its width to 100%, you will get a very tall image, as the browser is scaling it accordingly.

Show us your raw HTML of your e-mail.  I suspect that MailChimp is actually converting your height to `min-height`.

Comment: Thanks, took another look at it and its working now :). Ended up making 2 images